# How to install ochem for texlive

Tags: 10.10, latex

I found this package for latex that gives me the ability to typeset organic structural formulae and reaction schemes for chemistry. I'm having trouble with installing it though.

I read through the installation steps in the manual and it tells me that I need to edit the `install.cfg.UNIX` file which contains:

```
[PATH]
BINDIR=/usr/local/ochem
M4BINDIR=/usr/bin
INCDIR=/usr/local/ochem
DVIPSDIR=/usr/local/tetex/dvips/ochem
STYLEDIR=/usr/local/tetex/tex/latex/ochem
MODULDIR=/usr/local/ochem
DOCDIR=/usr/local/ochem/doc

[SYSTEM]
SYSTEM=UNIX
```

So I edited the file to this:

```
[PATH]
BINDIR=/usr/share/ochem
M4BINDIR=/usr/bin
INCDIR=/usr/share/ochem
DVIPSDIR=/usr/share/texmf-texlive/dvips/ochem
STYLEDIR=/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ochem
MODULDIR=/usr/share/ochem
DOCDIR=/usr/share/ochem/doc

[SYSTEM]
SYSTEM=UNIX
```

When I try to install the package, it says that it works, but when I try to typeset one of the examples, it tells me that it can't find `ochem.sty`. I then tried navigating to the directories that the install was supposed to make and they didn't exist. So I made the directories manually and tried the install again. I still get the missing `ochem.sty` error.

Did I edit `install.cfg.UNIX` correctly? My latex distribution is texlive 2009 on Ubuntu 10.10.

EDIT: I did try running `sudo texhash` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it will work if you have a copy of ochem.sty in the same location as your latex source file it is likely located in /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ochem, if this works then it is likely that you need to just run; sudo mktexlsr in your terminal for latex to re-examine all of your style files,

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `sudo texhash` to update LaTex database of local packages. Without this, LaTeX can't find them.

Comment: I tried that and latex still can't find the `ochem.sty` file.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to look for graphical packages using synaptic under the term "chemistry."